# 'CountVectorizer()' splitting on space instead of on comma

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp, tokenize

So in my dataframe I have a column 'Actors' that contains multiple 'first_name last name' of actors.

e.g: 'Dennis Christopher,Dennis Quaid,Daniel Stern' as type 'category'

When I use `CountVectorizer().fit_transform(df['Actors'])` it will sparse the above group as 6 words. I would like the function to not consider the ' '(space) between names but only the ',' so that with the previous example it would be sparse into 3 words.

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
Actors_f = vectorizer.fit_transform(df.loc[df['Actors'].notna(), 'Actors'])
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Maybe you can alter the `regex` used in `token_pattern` parameter.  Refer the [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

Answer (score 3):

Similarly as in this question: [How to treat number with decimals or with commas as one word in countVectorizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57325870/how-to-treat-number-with-decimals-or-with-commas-as-one-word-in-countvectorizer) you have to change the regular expression which is used to tokenize the input.

As the [documentation says](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), the default regular expression is:

```
token_pattern='(?u)\b\w\w+\b'
```

Which matches:

`(/u)` - unicode characters

`\b` - word boundary (e.g. space)

`\w` - a word

`\w+` - consequtive words up to ...

`\b` - another word boundary (e.g. the end of string)

What you need is this:

```
 token_pattern='(?u)[a-zA-Z][a-z ]+'
```

In particular, the space character is included in the token which makes catching name + surname as one token.

Check [the regular expression documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for the meaning of the regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below tokenizer to split by comma in your case:

> vectorizer = CountVectorizer(**tokenizer=lambda x: x.split(',')**)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do so with

```
bigram_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2), min_df=1)
bigram_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Actors'])
```

Comment: Still, I'm not sure why it worked because I read that a n-gram could be a contiguous sequence of n items (not especially words) so why dit it interpret it as words. I guess a more rigorous way to so would be by setting 'token_pattern '

Answer (score 0):

Probably a more readable and intuitive method

```
import re
re_exp = r"\,"
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda text: re.split(re_exp,text))
```

The [Scikit-Learn Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) says

tokenizer: callable, default=None
Override the string tokenization step while preserving the preprocessing and n-grams generation steps. Only applies if analyzer == 'word'.